# Align multiple divs vertically each div having same percentage height

Tags: html, css

My pen

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/dqGDk

I want to vertically align 3 divs inside a wrapper div. Each of the 3 divs should have a height of 33%. I can make the layout work when the divs has a height of 33px but I need it as percentage because the wrapper div`s height changes dynamically. Sometimes its 100px height, sometimes 70px etc...

I just want that all 3 are always correct align by using percentage height.

What is the approach aligning divs with percentage?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapperDiv" style="height:100px;">
<div id="navigationWheelerContainer">
  <div id="navigationWheeler" >
    <div id="previewTemplate" >1</div>
    <div id="previewTemplate" style="background-color: #0094ff;">2</div>
    <div id="previewTemplate" >3</div>
  </div>
   <div id="toggleButtonRight" >◄</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigationWheeler {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: lightgray;   
    display: inline-block;
}

#navigationWheelerContainer {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

#previewTemplate {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 33%; /* 33px; works but is not dynamic to the wrapper div */
}
#toggleButtonRight {
    width: 40px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle link for the above scenario?

Comment: What is the point using id="previewTemplate" for 3 DIV tag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier if you change to use an unordered list. Also the ID `previewTemplate` should be a class as the ID has to be unique.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapperDiv" style="height:100px;">
<div id="navigationWheelerContainer">
  <ul id="navigationWheeler" >
    <li class="previewTemplate" >Testing</li>
    <li class="previewTemplate" style="background-color: #0094ff;">2</li>
    <li class="previewTemplate" >3</li>
  </ul>
   <div id="toggleButtonRight" >◄</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you can set `.previewTemplate` in the CSS to have a height of 33%. Also add `list-style: none;` to get rid of the bullets. Then in `#navigationWheeler` set `padding-left: 0;` to get rid of the spacing.

**CSS**

```
#navigationWheeler {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: lightgray;   
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#navigationWheelerContainer {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.previewTemplate {
    height: 33%;
    list-style: none;
}

#toggleButtonRight {
    width: 40px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now when the height of your `#wrapperDiv` changes the li with class `.previewTemplate` will change it's height.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3kZA/18/). Also you should avoid using inline CSS. Have all your styles inside your CSS file. Makes it easier to manage in the long run.

**EDIT** Adding `padding-left: 0` to the CSS for the `#navigationWheeler`

**EDIT** Updating the JSFiddle to take in account the padding-left for the `<ul>`

Comment: Chrome28 does not show your li-tags rendered. Something is wrong with your fiddle.

Comment: @Elisa It's working for me, I'm using Chrome28. I just checked and you have to horizontal scroll to see the numbers in the li. I just simply used what you provided, I didn't alter much.

Comment: sorry I havent seen the horizontal scrollbars and thought the layout is broken because I havent seen the numbers... have you any idea from where the left vertical space besides the numbers comes? I can not spot the width setting for this. There numbers are here but the number divs does not consider the height of the parent. I can change the parent height to 300px then I expect every div has a height of 100px but thats not the case.

Comment: Oh, yes I see what you mean now. The `<ul>` have padding left automatically added to it. You have to specify in the CSS that you want no padding. I've made the changes to the JSFiddle and the sample code above. I simply added `padding-left: 0;` to `#navigationWheeler`.

Answer (score 1):

I use flex-box, works way better the list items plus you can place ul,ol,il in flex-box.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/02/css3-flexible-box-layout-module-aka-flex-box-introduction-and-demostest-cases/

Comment: That is for 1e8/9 its call flexiblebox

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/14/ie10-platform-preview-and-css-features-for-adaptive-layouts.aspx

Comment: Try this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/14/ie10-platform-preview-and-css-features-for-adaptive-layouts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using list items instead of div's. You can easily style and their syntax is more focused on alignment then a div. Also, Your wrapper div's need to be a percentage as well, you can't do a 10% height in a 100px wrapper div..